# Controlling Arduino Ethernet with a Separate Webpage

Tags: controls, arduino

I have an arduino uno and ethernet shield and have a code written to access it over my network and click on ON or OFF and it will turn the pin on or off. I want to be able to make a schedule and a more aesthetically pleasing page to do it, so I am trying to make a webpage that has a scheduling function in order for me to set a date and time and then for the page  to click the ON button, on the page hosted by my arduino board.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit? I assume you are saying that you are at a state where you have written an application on desktop which could access your arduino via network and turn some pins on and off. And now you want to create a webpage which could leverage the code to access arduino. Am I right?

Comment: Basically, the code written on the arduino is the code to turn on the pins plus basic html so that when I type the arduino's I.P. address in on my browser I can access the arduino's html page that its displaying and click on or off to turn pins on. I am going to place the arduino outside my firewall so that I can access it from outside my network but I want to be able to create a webpage that will look nice and have a schedule that I can set so that when the schedule reaches the time and date I set, it goes to the arduinos html page and clicks the on button.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a way to schedule tasks on the arduino, similar to the way cron is used in Linux for scheduling tasks.

There are a few cron implementations for arduino, such as this [one](https://github.com/aaronds/arduino-unix-time/blob/master/UnixTimeCron/examples/unix_time_cron_example/unix_time_cron_example.pde)